# Ternary operator gives unexpected results when printed

Tags: java, string, return-value

Today I encountered a strange problem with the ternary operator that I cannot exaplain. I could handle this problem by inserting it between parentheses, however I would appreciate much if you can tell the explication for this behaviour.

Take this example code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plant plant = new Plant();
        System.out.println("{\"name\":\""+plant.getName()!=null?plant.getName():plant.getId()+"\"}");
        System.out.println("{\"name\":\""+(plant.getName()!=null?plant.getName():plant.getId())+"\"}");
    }
}
class Plant {
    public String getId() {
        return "Hello";
    }
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
null

{"name":"Hello"}
```

I cannot exaplain the first 'null'. How in the world I can get a null for the 1st syso statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getName()` method returns `null`.

So when you call

```
System.out.println("{\"name\":\""+plant.getName()!=null?plant.getName():plant.getId()+"\"}");
```

`"name":` + `null` is not `null`

Hence it prints `plant.getName()` which is `null`

Answer (score 4):

```
"{\"name\":\""+plant.getName()!=null?plant.getName():plant.getId()+"\"}"
```

is evaluated as :

```
("{\"name\":\""+plant.getName()!=null)?plant.getName():plant.getId()+"\"}"
```

`"{\"name\":\""+plant.getName()` is not null, even if `plant.getName()` is null. Therefore `plant.getName()` is returned by the ternary conditional operator, and it's null, so `null` is printed.